# How to make a list covariant :- scala

Tags: scala

Consider SubFoo extends Foo . I have a construct like this

```
trait SomeTrait
{

def someFun(a : List[Foo], ...) -> List[Foo]
.
.
.
}
```

Now in my code I would like to do y:List[SubFoo] = someFun(List(x),...) where x:SubFoo and **y should be of type List[SubFoo]**. But I get the error message expected List(SubFoo), actual: List(Foo): -
How do I do that with the following constraints:-

1. I don't want to add a type parameter to SomeTrait ( like SomeTrait[+A]) because SomeTrait is used widely in our codebase without passing any types.
2. I wouldn't like to change y:List[SubFoo] to List[Foo] . I am looking for a solution that does the required change where someFun is defined.
3. The most obvious : do not change someFun to someFun(a : List[SubFoo], ...) -> List[SubFoo] . Nada

Let me know if there is a solution respecting the constraints or which at-least satisfies constraint-1.

Thanks

Comment: `def someFun[T <: Foo](a: List[T]): List[T]`? Depends on what you want to do with your `someFun`.

Comment: Variance is not in your way. Lists *are* covariant. List[SubClass] is a subtype of List[SomeClass], if SubClass <: SomeClass. Your problem is that you're trying to forcefully cast a type to a more narrow type (that is, a subtype). Apple is a Fruit, but Fruit is not (necessarily) an Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, variance is not your way. Lists *are* covariant.

Without knowing more about your problem, it sounds like you're trying get a sublist of `Some[Foo]`, where the sublist consists entirely of `SubFoo`s.

So given

```
sealed trait Foo
case class SubFoo(baz: Int) extends Foo
case class OtherSubFoo(bam: String) extends Foo
```

it sounds like you would want a list of

```
List(SubFoo(1), SubFoo(2), OtherSubFoo("a"), SubFoo(25)): List[Foo]
```

to be converted to

```
List(SubFoo(1), SubFoo(2), SubFoo(25)): List[SubFoo]
```

---

Type signatures exist for a reason. If you're trying to convert a `List[Foo]` to a `List[SubFoo]`, you need your conversion function type to reflect that. Here is something you could potentially do:

```
trait SomeTrait {

  def someFun(foos: List[Foo]): List[SubFoo] = {

    val listOfSubFoos = foos.map {
      case (sub: SubFoo) => Some(sub)
      case _ => None
    }

    // now you have a list of type List[Option[SubFoo]],
    // and want to flatten it to a List[SubFoo]
    listOfSubFoos.flatten
  }
}
```

There would be other ways to structure it, but the core idea here is that you'd need a function that reduces a `List[Foo]` to  a `List[SubFoo]`. You can't have a type `List[Foo]` and guarantee that every `Foo` is a `SubFoo` in the type system. If you need something like that, you'd most likely have to rethink your type hierarchy here.

Just remember the basic structure of inheritance. All `SubFoo`s are `Foo`s, but not all `Foo`s are `SubFoo`s.

Comment: `foos.collect { case sub: SubFoo => sub }`, but I seriously doubt it's what OP wants